# Div Appear After 5 Seconds Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems getting a div to appear using jquery after 5 seconds.

right now I was using

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#message").delay(delay).fadeIn(5000);
      });

But it's not working (#message being the name of the div serounding the content I'd like to show)

If anyone could help me get it working that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the HTML chunk containing the DIV you are trying to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a `delay` variable defined that you are passing into the `delay` function?  What you pass to [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) should be how long to wait until doing the next function.  I'd think you'd want something like this:

```
$('#message').delay(5000).fadeIn(5000);
```

Comment: @Belgin Fish - What version of IE?  Is there an error or does nothing happen?  Hard to say without seeing your entire code.  If you post it I'll check it out.

Comment: hey, ie 8 and just nothings happening

I read somewhere to use 

    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#message").delay(5000).fadeIn(500).css('filter', 'none');
    });

but its still not working, and I would post the code but my buddy says I can't :(

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code.  My simple testing example works with my code in IE7.  If a page with nothing but that div and that code still doesn't work, I'd remove the `delay(5000)` and see if the `fadeIn` works ok.  If that works, I'd remove the `fadeIn` and change some css after the `delay(5000)` and see if that works.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it not [working](http://jsbin.com/udogo3/)? Don't forget to set the delay!